# Bootstrap modal on show function not passing value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to pass id of the button to modal but seems cant get through and the console didnt show any error so i dont understand whats the problem.

I have edited the form attribute :

```js
$('.showModal').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $('#data').modal('show');
  $('#data').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    $('.form #username').val(id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="showModal" id="0379">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit">
    </i>
</a>

modal

<div class="modal fade" id="data" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form method="post" action="" id="modalForm" class="form">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="card" style="width: 29.3rem;">
            <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/" />
            <img class="card-img-top" src="/../project/resources/assets/images/download.svg" alt="Card image cap">
            </input>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">NIS</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="username" value="i_want_button_id_here">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modalSubmit">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `.data('id')` that mean you're trying to target the property `data-id` when you've just `id`, you could use **[`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** instead, like :

```
var id = $(this).prop('id');
```

You could try to target the previous anchor like :

```
$('#data').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    var id = $(this).prev('a').prop('id');

    $('.form #username').val(id);
});
```

Comment: You're welcome, try my uspdate using `$(this).prev('a').prop('id')`.

Comment: shows an error Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined.

Comment: Put the line before `$('.form #username').val(id);` directly

Comment: somehow when i rewrite the code, its now working. but still shows an error if i log that id. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I think that is bacause you dont have class `.form`. You try to set value using this

```
$('.form #username').val(id);
```

Did you mean tag `<form>`? If yes, this should looks like that

```
$('form #username').val(id);
```

Also when you want to get val you should use `attr` instead of `data`

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: still not working, this is one of many data i want to edit and i want to pass the id to modal so i can edit it related to the data i click.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `id` variable is `undefined` (try to `console.log(id)` it).

In order to access the `id` attribute on the link that opens the modal, use  `this.id`:

`var id = this.id;`

Or with jQuery [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

`var id = $(this).attr('id');`

Comment: i change it to $(this).attr('id') but it shows error Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (data-siswa:1497)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)